# Use for statement with array to find next true

Tags: xcode, if-statement, for-loop, swift

Im trying to use the code below to find the biggest number that's not true; however, if  a true variable comes before the biggest number I want it to give me the number below that one. How can I change my code to accomplish this?

```
var firstRow = [1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false, 5: true, 6: false]
var smallest = Int.max
var largest = 0
var playerLoc = "3"

for (number, bool) in firstRow {
if playerLoc != "1" && playerLoc != "30"{
    if bool == false && number < smallest {
        smallest = number
        var smallString = ("\(smallest)")
        if smallString == playerLoc {
            smallest = Int.max

        }
        else {
            smallest = number

        }
    }
}
else {
    smallest = Int.max
}
if playerLoc != "6" && playerLoc != "36" {

    if bool == false && number > largest {
        largest = number
    }
}
else {
    largest = 0
}

}
println(smallest)
println(largest)
```

So for example this code would set largest equal to 4 if it worked correctly and smallest equal to 1
UPDATE:
When using this line of code I get the error Array Index Out of Range

```
var firstRow = [(1, false), (2, false), (3, false), (4, false), (5, false), (6, false)]
```

However, if I use it in the playground it works fine.

I've narrowed the problem down to this code.

```
if two.contains(player.position) || two.contains(opponent.position) ||     two.contains(block3.position) {
    firstRow[2].1 = true
} else {
    firstRow[2].1 = false
}
```

Comment: are you aware that dictionaries are unordered collections? so the items in firstRow won't necessarily be iterated over in that order.

Comment: I did not know that. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: an array of tuples maybe: `var a = Array<(Int, Bool)>()`

Comment: Whats the format for my int and bools then? Just commas?

Comment: post the loop and any code that accesses the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array instead of a dictionary if the order matters.

```
var firstRow = [(1, false), (2, false), (3, false), (4, false), (5, true), (6, false)]
```

Then you can iterate like this:

```
for var i = 0; i < firstRow.count; ++i){
    if (firstRow[i].1){
        if (i == 0){
            // handle this condition
        } else {
            smallest = firstRow[i-1].0
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I found that if there are two trues in a row it will return both. I want it to stop when it returns the very first one

Comment: Im getting an Array index out of range error when I use an array like you showed me

Comment: if the first item is true you will get an error trying to access an element at index [-1]. i've edited the answer again

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I switched to the array it started at 0 instead of 1 so if I called 6 it gave the error. So I had to start at 0 and go to 5.